# Is it necessary to use db2 in Websphere?

Tags: websphere, datasource

Currently we are using Oracle in weblogic. 
Can't we use same Oracle in Websphere in the part of weblogic to websphere migration?
is it necessary to use db2 in Websphere?

Answer (score 1):

No...
We did used mySQL through XAMPP many a times...

It worked good enough.

PS:We used mySQL because we were not acquainted with DB2 by that time.

Comment: Can anybody please let me know how datasource part can be managed during weblogic to websphere migration.

Comment: Notice MySQL is not a supported Product. if it works that is good but it is not a supported DB with WebSphere Application Server

Comment: I found that oracle is a supported DB with WebSphere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Oracle, and other non-DB2 databases.

You will need to get the Oracle JDBC drivers, which are easily downloadable from Oracle. Then all the set up can be done through the WebSphere console.

There are various Oracle-specific setup steps in the Info Center [for example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp) but I've used Oracle many times without problem.

Answer (score 1):

Any database with a JDBC driver should work with WebSphere. The included and officially supported JDBC drivers are [listed here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27012389#jdbc) and include DB2, Oracle, Informix, Sybase, and MS SQL Server.

But, for instance, we've used PostgreSQL in the past as well by just copying and configuring the driver jar files.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you read this

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247870.html?Open

This provides your good information on how to migrate to WebSphere Application Server. I am assuming you are referring to the application server and not to other products in the WebSphere family of products.

As mentioned by the others a number of databases are supported by WebSphere. As long as you choose a supported version of Oracle you should not have trouble.

If the book does not provide you with the answers post in specific areas that you need assistance on.

HTH

Manglu